# hiding the close button on a Jquery dialog that is bound to knockout view model

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I need to hide the jquery dialog close button (the 'X' on the top right corner) on a dialog that is bound to a knockout view model.

here is the div with the knock out binding

```
 <div id="runDialog" data-bind="dialog: { autoOpen: autoOpenDialog, modal: isDialogModal,   title: dialogTitle  }, openDialog: dialogItem">
 </div
```

this is utilizing the  [Knockout.Bindings.js](https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bindings)

in the past i have been able to just control it by using the open event and hide it that way

```
open: function (event, ui) {
        $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close", ui.dialog).hide(); 
        },
```

I can add this to the knockout dialog binding, but that is pretty ugly anyone have a better way to do this here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use next construction, desribed on [jQuery Dialog API page](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) in section
**Hiding the close button**
1) Add css rule

```
.no-close .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {
  display: none;
}
```

2) In knockout binding use `dialogClass: 'no-close'`

```
<div id="runDialog" data-bind="dialog: { autoOpen: autoOpenDialog, modal: isDialogModal,   title: dialogTitle, dialogClass : 'no-close'  }, openDialog: dialogItem">
 </div>
```

[**JSFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ExPhg/)

Comment: beautiful! this works perfectly and is a very clean way of doing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Can you do it in css?

```
.ui-dialog-titlebar-close {display: none;}
```

Comment: the only problem is I don't want to hide it for every dialog, just this instance

Comment: It doesn't have to be a global style, you can restrict to a container element. #runDialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close or similar

Comment: ok good point I may work with that and mark your answer if it does it. thanks!

Comment: .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {display: none;} works but #runDialog .ui-dialog-titlebar-close {display: none;} does not. very weird.

Comment: It looks like you might want to wrap your runDialog div with another. I thought the UIDialog would have a unique Id to reference but it looks not

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the binding handler (Pseudo code)

```
ko.bindingHandlers = {
   init: function(element, valueAccessor)  {
      $element = $(element);
      var config = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
      if(!config.showCloseButton) {
         config.open: function (event, ui) {
           $($element, ui.dialog).hide(); 
         }
      }
   }
};
```